# Electron React redux. Updating the state in a form window is not reflected in the main window

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, electron

Here is my reducer:

```
   export default (state = intial_state ,actions) => {


        switch(actions.type) {
            case USER_INPUT_CHANGED : return {
                ...state,reddit_user:actions.payload
            }
            break;

            case USER_INPUT_SUBMITTED : 



                return {...state,users: [...state.users, actions.payload],duplicateItem:false};



            break;
            default:
                    return state;
        }
    }
```

I have two windows. A mainwindow and another one createUserForm.js
To  handle multiple windows I'm using  **react-router-dom**.

When I submit the a new user in the form window the the state update is reflected in THAT window but not the main window. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It's really hard to help with the information you provided. Does the store get updated properly? How you `connect` to the store in the component that is not updated? Do you use `PureComponent`s that for some reason don't detect state change?

Comment: Yes. The store seems to get updated when I check from the addUserWindow, I simply console logged inside the renderer function to check it. But it doesn't seem to work in the main window.

Comment: I'm not using pureComponent

Comment: Did you get the solution? I am facing same issue